# Do I need to worry about denial of service with CreateMutex if I use "Local\"?

Tags: c, winapi

I would like to use `CreateMutex` as a means to limit my application to a single-instance. (Specifically, one instance per user.)

[The MSDN documentation to `CreateMutex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682411.aspx) warns about the possibility of a malicious user snatching and hoarding the mutex first.  However, if I create the mutex using the session namespace (via the "Local\" prefix), is that still something that I need to be concerned about?  If so, in what circumstance could a different user create a mutex in my session?

Comment: I think you'd better worry about a malicious *program*.  Like one from your competitor that starts itself up at login and creates that mutex to block you.  They will of course claim that it is important to solve a "compatibility problem".

Comment: @HansPassant If that malicious program is running as the same user as mine, I don't see what I could do to prevent that anyway.  I'm not interested in an arms race.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `Local\` namespace will keep the mutex isolated to the current desktop session, but you should also follow the other recommendations in that paragraph:

> To prevent this situation, create a randomly named mutex and store the name so that it can only be obtained by an authorized user. Alternatively, you can use a file for this purpose. To limit your application to one instance per user, create a locked file in the user's profile directory.

Generate the mutex name using something like [CoCreateGuid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms688568%28VS.85%29.aspx), store it in a registry key and use that, or alternatively lock a file in the user's profile directory.

The reason for the recommendation to use a difficult to guess ID is, in the unlikely case that multiple processes belonging to different users are running in the same session, that your process has a mechanism for using a hard to guess key name that can be protected from the other account by using the registry ACL mechanism - i.e. blocking other non-administrative users from reading the value keeps it safe in this case. You gain a similar protection in the case of using a lock file as the default ACLs on your home directory would prevent the other users from creating or modifying the file[*]. Again, I state that this is actually an unlikely case, but it is possible (processes can be launched from system services using different user credentials to the user logged in in a particular session).

Are you trying to limit it to 'single instance per user' or 'single instance per desktop session'?

If it's one per session, then the `Local\` mutex is appropriate.

If it's one per user (regardless of session) then a lock on a file in the user's profile directory is more appropriate.

You can configure windows to permit multiple remote terminal service logins with the same username - by default it's one session per user.

<sup>[*] In the event that the user is running with your credentials or Administrator credentials all these mechanisms are ineffective as they can just read this secret key. The idea is protection from other accounts running in the same session</sup>

Comment: But *why* should I follow those recommendations?  In what situation could a malicious user take my "Local\" mutex first?

Comment: Because it's a defensive programming style. Your actual concern is against malicious *apps*, not users, and those generally end up running **in your session anyway**.

Comment: Trying to defend against a malicious application running as the same user seems futile.  What prevents that application from creating a mutex with my random registry value or locking my file before me?

Comment: And my concern *is* about malicious users.  One user steals a mutex that prevents the administrator from running some program.  And once a user runs a malicious program, it's game over for that user anyway; I can't do anything for that user.

Comment: If your application is running as the administrator user, the registry value for the mutex can have permissions only permitting the administrator user read it. J. Random user can't read the value and thus doesn't know the name of the mutex

Comment: But what happens if the malicious user is administrator? Then you, my friend, have bigger issues than stopping your program from running

Comment: If the administrator is malicious, it's game over.  That's not the case I'm concerned with.  And your statement about J. Random User not being able to read another user's registry value is *exactly* my point.  Using a random registry value (or a locked file) protects against malicious *users*, not malicious applications running as the same user.  But if using "Local\" *also* protects against malicious users, why bother with the random registry value or locked file?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29041/discussion-between-petesh-and-jamesdlin)

Comment: BTW, I'll accept this answer if you update it to mention what you explained in chat (that programs running in the current session might be running as different users).